# Undefined index when Grouping and sum values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, notice

I am using the below code to group the array `$summary` by *currency* and get the sum of grouped duration and cost. So far I am able to group and sum the array but since the array cells `$result[$split['currency']]['duration']` and `$result[$split['currency']]['cost']` are undefined I am getting notice when I run the code. How can I remove the notice without using `error_reporting(0)`?

### Code

```
foreach ($summary as $split) {

            if (isset($split['currency'])) {
                $result[$split['currency']]['duration'] += $split['duration'];
                $result[$split['currency']]['cost'] += $split['cost'];
            } else {
                $result[0]['duration'] += $split['duration'];
                $result[0]['cost'] += $split['cost'];
            }
        }
```

### EDIT

```
$summary = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [currency] => SGD
        [duration] => 8.00
        [cost] => 228.57
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [currency] => SGD
        [duration] => 8.00
        [cost] => 228.57
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [currency] => 
        [duration] => 8.00
        [cost] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [currency] => MYR
        [duration] => 12.00
        [cost] => 342.86
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [currency] => SGD
        [duration] => 8.00
        [cost] => 228.57
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [currency] => MYR
        [duration] => 12.00
        [cost] => 342.86
    )
```

`$result` will be as show below

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [currency] => SGD
        [duration] => 24
        [cost] => 685.71
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [currency] => MYR
        [duration] => 24
        [cost] => 685.72
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [currency] => 
        [duration] => 8
        [cost] => 0
    )
```

)

Comment: show us the input array values and expected outcome. thanks

Comment: what is the possible outputs of `$split['currency']`?

Comment: show us your array values so that it will be easy for us to give you a solution.

Comment: `var_dump($summary);` and post the result.

Comment: Edit: included arrays in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the array first:

```
foreach ($summary as $split) {
        if (isset($split['currency'])) {
            if (!isset($result[$split['currency']]) {
                $result[$split['currency']] = [
                    'duration' => 0,
                    'cost' => 0
                ];
            }
            $result[$split['currency']]['duration'] += $split['duration'];
            $result[$split['currency']]['cost'] += $split['cost'];
        } else {
            $result[0]['duration'] += $split['duration'];
            $result[0]['cost'] += $split['cost'];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Test existence of `$result` array indexes too.

```
foreach ($summary as $split) {
    if (isset($split['currency'])) {
        if(!isset($result[$split['currency']])) {
        $result[$split['currency']]['duration'] = $split['duration'];
        $result[$split['currency']]['cost'] = $split['cost'];  
        } else {
        $result[$split['currency']]['duration'] += $split['duration'];
        $result[$split['currency']]['cost'] += $split['cost'];
        }
    } else {
        $result[0]['duration'] += $split['duration'];
        $result[0]['cost'] += $split['cost'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need for the extra condition block.

Use `currency` as temporary keys.  On the first encounter of a `currency`, store the whole row. Otherwise, add the current iteration's `duration` and `cost` to the stored group. When finished looping, re-index the array with `array_values()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZEoU4))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['currency']])) {
        $result[$row['currency']] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$row['currency']]['duration'] += $row['duration'];
        $result[$row['currency']]['cost'] += $row['cost'];
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'currency' => 'SGD',
    'duration' => 16.0,
    'cost' => 457.14,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'currency' => NULL,
    'duration' => 8.0,
    'cost' => NULL,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'currency' => 'MYR',
    'duration' => 24.0,
    'cost' => 685.72,
  ),
)
```