# Grouping and adding values multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

### Code

```
foreach ($summary as $split) {
    if (isset($split['currency'])) {
        if (!isset($result[$split['currency']]) {
            $result[$split['currency']] = [
                'duration' => 0,
                'cost' => 0
            ];
        }
        $result[$split['currency']]['employee'] = $split['employee'];
        $result[$split['currency']]['duration'] += $split['duration'];
        $result[$split['currency']]['cost'] += $split['cost'];
    } else {
        $result[0]['employee'] = $split['employee'];
        $result[0]['duration'] += $split['duration'];
        $result[0]['cost'] += $split['cost'];
    }
}
```

My array looks like this

```
$summary = Array
(
[0] => Array
   (
    [employee] => John
    [currency] => SGD
    [duration] => 8.00
    [cost] => 228.57
)

[1] => Array
   (
    [employee] => Fil
    [currency] => SGD
    [duration] => 8.00
    [cost] => 228.57
 )

[2] => Array
(
    [employee] => John
    [currency] => 
    [duration] => 8.00
    [cost] => 
)

[3] => Array
(
    [employee] => John
    [currency] => MYR
    [duration] => 12.00
    [cost] => 342.86
)

[4] => Array
(
    [employee] => Sam
    [currency] => SGD
    [duration] => 8.00
    [cost] => 228.57
)

[5] => Array
(
    [employee] => Fil
    [currency] => MYR
    [duration] => 12.00
    [cost] => 342.86
)
```

I want to group the above array by employee and currency. What I require is similar to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607559/undefined-index-when-grouping-and-sum-values-in-multidimensional-array)

but in this grouping is done for currency only so in the output array there will be 3 inner array only.

**I want to group the array such that the result will group first employee and then currency. So there will be 3 inner array for each employee**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the name as the key in $result array before currency key,

```
foreach ($summary as $split) {
        if (isset($split['currency'])) {
            if (!isset($result[$split['employee']][$split['currency']]) {
                $result[$split['employee']][$split['currency']] = [
                    'duration' => 0,
                    'cost' => 0
                ];
            }
            $result[$split['employee']][$split['currency']]['employee'] = $split['employee'];
            $result[$split['employee']][$split['currency']]['duration'] += $split['duration'];
            $result[$split['employee']][$split['currency']]['cost'] += $split['cost'];
        } else {
            $result[0]['employee'] = $split['employee'];
            $result[0]['duration'] += $split['duration'];
            $result[0]['cost'] += $split['cost'];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$in = [
   ['employee'=>'A','currency'=>'USD','duration'=>8.00,'cost'=>42]
  ,['employee'=>'A','currency'=>'SDU','duration'=>8.00,'cost'=>42]
  ,['employee'=>'A','currency'=>'','duration'=>8.00,'cost'=>42]
  ,['employee'=>'B','currency'=>'USD','duration'=>8.00,'cost'=>42]
  ,['employee'=>'B','currency'=>'SDU','duration'=>8.00,'cost'=>42]
  ,['employee'=>'B','currency'=>'','duration'=>8.00,'cost'=>42]
];

$result = [];
$groupSum = function ($v) use (&$result) {
    $emp = $v['employee'];
    $curr = $v['currency'];
    if ( !array_key_exists($emp,$result) ) {
      $result[$emp] = [];
    }
    if ( !array_key_exists($curr,$result[$emp]) ) {
        $result[$emp][$curr] = ['duration'=>0,'cost'=>0];
    }
    $result[$emp][$curr]['duration'] += $v['duration'];
    $result[$emp][$curr]['cost'] += $v['cost'];
};
array_map($groupSum,$in);

print_r($result);
```